# get daily price change in coinbase api + different crypto currency as only BC

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I use the coinbase API to write a small script in `python`. Now i want to get the 'daily change price' (see image with the red square).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crlTQ.png)

Also, is there a way to get the price for litecoin, ethereum, etc? I tried this:

```
client = Client(api_key, api_secret, api_version=version)

currency_code = 'USD'
price = client.get_spot_price(currency=currency_code)

print 'Current price in %s: %s' % (currency_code, price.amount)
```

but this only returns the price for bitcoins. I also tried

```
currency_code = 'ETH-USD'
```

and similar things, but its always bitcoin.

Comment: <br>
You may check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255624/coinbase-api-et-exchange-rates-and-get-currencies-failure) which I believe covers the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
price = client.get_spot_price(currency_pair = 'LTC-EUR')
```

instead of LTC-EUR you can use any pair that exists on Coinbase.