# CoinBase API - et_exchange_rates and get_currencies failure.

Tags: python-3.x, coinbase-api

Hi when writing a simple python script to test Coinbase Features as per documentation I am getting the following results:

[get_exchange_rates(currency='GBP')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pEqx.png)

I encounter a similar problem when I try to get the price of a given currency that is not BTC-USD:

```
price = client.get_buy_price(currency_pair = 'BTC-GBP')
print(price)
```

RESULT:

> {   "amount": "13788.39",   "base": "BTC",   "currency": "USD" }

Is this a problem with the API, or am I doing this incorrectly?

**Additional info:**Using API keys with all functionality allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like is a known [bug](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python/issues/32) which hasn't been published yet. It defaults all the currency pairs to BTC-USD.
You may try instead using **requests.get()** providing the required headers for authentication or even follow the provided [example](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication) on the developers site.